# Почему у меня не работает сортировка с помощью ORDER BY GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, pdo

Пробовал написать запрос по [данному ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066453/mysql-group-by-and-order-by)
для сортировки таблицы по передаваемому параметру.

Вот код с запросом:

```
$tasks_request = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tasks ORDER BY :param ASC) AS tmp_table GROUP BY UPPER(:param) LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset) ";
$stmp = $this->db->prepare($tasks_request);
$stmp->bindValue(":param", $ord_by, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmp->bindValue(":limit", $tasks_per_page, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmp->bindValue(":offset", $offset, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmp->execute();
```

В итоге в выборке получаю только первую запись, а у меня их в таблице 5.

Пытался сделать так:

```
$tasks_request = "SELECT * FROM tasks GROUP BY UPPER(:param) ORDER BY :param LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset ";
```

Результат тот же.

Пытался сделать без `GROUP BY`:

```
$tasks_request = "SELECT * FROM tasks ORDER BY :param LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset ";
```

Выдаёт все нужные записи по (по лимиту их 3), но не сортирует.

В **phpMyAdmin** выполнил это:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Тоже не помогло...
Параметры я проверял, все валидные, вывод ошибок у меня включён, при запросе их нет. В чём же тогда проблема?

Answer (score 1):

prepared statements не могут менять структуру запроса. Поля в `order by` или `group by` - это всё ещё структура запроса.

Формально вы отправляете

```
ORDER BY 'string' ASC
```

Внимание на кавычки. Просто строковую константу, одно и то же значение для всех строк результата. Конечно сортировка ничего полезного не сделает, если у всех строк одно и то же значение для сортировки.

---

При сортировке у вас заведомо известен список возможных полей, по которым вы можете разрешить сортировать. Вот и проверьте переданное пользователем значение, есть ли оно среди допустимых. Если есть - подставьте в сам текст запроса. То есть проверка по белому списку, что безопасно с точки зрения `sql injection`.

---

Пытаться через выключенный `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` получать первую строку в группе - к большим приключениям. Поищите (или задайте новый вопрос если найдёте) как эта задача должна нормально решаться для вашей версии СУБД.

Comment: У меня Mysql 5.7.29. Т.е. для каждой версии есть разные способы сортировать?

Comment: То есть в древних стремительно приближающихся к EOL 5.х недоступны те же оконные функции

Answer (score 1):

Вот так работает:

```
$tasks_request = "SELECT * FROM tasks ORDER BY "."`".$ord_by."`"." LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset ";
```

Конечно же- это костыль. В моём случае значение приходит из выпадающего списка, поэтому в
`$ord_by` навряд ли получится запихнуть SQL Injection. Но, в целом, этот вариант решения проблемы плохой, хоть и работает. Если кто знает более адекватное решение данной проблемы- буду рад отметить как правильный ответ.